# How can I GroupBy this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is my code :

```
objectList = (from MyObject obj in MyObjects
             select r).ToList();
```

I'd like to return the list of each record with a "distinct" obj.ID. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the list of type `IGrouping<int, MyObject>` (note, I assume that `ID` has type `int`):

```
groupedList = (from obj in MyObjects
             group obj by obj.ID into grouped
             select grouped).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx):

```
var lookup = MyObjects.ToLookup(x => x.ID);
```

That lets you fetch all the values for any particular ID, or iterate over the groupings. It's eagerly evaluated, rather than `GroupBy`'s lazy evaluation, which is probably what you want in this case.

That's assuming I understood your request correctly - it's entirely possible that I didn't... it would be helpful if you could clarify.